# How to use a personalized property grid with a Chart class?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, customization, propertygrid

I am working on a graphing program and I want the user to customize their graph quickly and effectively. I have created a property grid which allows them to do that. I've populated it with the properties of a chart but removes certain elements I don't want the user to have access to. For instance I don't want the user to be able to have access to the accessibility options. So far what I have is

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        magRadioBox.Checked = true;
        PropertyGrid propertyGrid1 = new PropertyGrid();
        propertyGrid1.CommandsVisibleIfAvailable = true;
        propertyGrid1.Text = "Graph and Plotting Options";
        propertyGrid1.PropertyValueChanged += propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged;

        this.Controls.Add(propertyGrid1);
    }
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.Text = "MY Plot Program";
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = chart1; 
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {//some code that is populating my chart(chart1) with data 
 .... //chart1 being filled with data 
 }

private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s , PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
//Calling the method that will refresh my chart1 
myChart.Invalidate(); 
}
```

The above code is for my Form. The my "MyChart" class code below sets up my property grid. I automatically get all of the properties of a chart and then can "cherry pick" the ones I don't want the user to have by setting it to `[Browsable(false)]`

```
namespace FFT_Plotter
{ 
    [DefaultPropertyAttribute("Text")]
    public class MyChart : Chart 
    {
        public event EventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
EventHandler eh = propertyChanged;
if(eh !=null)
{
eh(sender, e);
}
        [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        public new System.Drawing.Color BackColor
        {
            get { return BackColor; }//Here back color is just an example of a property, not necessarily one that I would make non-Browsable
            set { 
base.BackColor = value; 
OnPropertyChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty);
}
        }
    }
}
```

The class above gets me so far as having a property grid that has all the properties of a chart and allows me to hide those properties as I see fit. However now I am stuck in understanding how to connect my `chart1` to my property grid. An example would be I've removed the text property from the grid. It's no longer visible to the user. Now I want to be able to say change `BackColor` in the grid which means my `chart1` back color changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I took your code and did the following and now changing the Background Color in the property grid changes the chart's background color:

Form1 -

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PropertyGrid propertyGrid1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //propertyGrid1 = new PropertyGrid();
        propertyGrid1.CommandsVisibleIfAvailable = true;
        propertyGrid1.Text = "Graph and Plotting Options";
        propertyGrid1.PropertyValueChanged += propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged;

        this.Controls.Add(propertyGrid1);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "MY Plot Program";
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = chart1; 
    }
    private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Calling the method that will refresh my chart1 
        chart1.Invalidate();
    }
}



[DefaultPropertyAttribute("Text")]
public class MyChart : Chart 
{

    public event EventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged !=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }

    [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public new string Text { get; set; }


    [BrowsableAttribute(true)]
    public new System.Drawing.Color BackColor
    {
        get { return base.BackColor; }//Here back color is just an example of a property, not necessarily one that I would make non-Browsable
        set 
        { 
            base.BackColor = value; 

            OnPropertyChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }    
    }     
}
```

- Also, in your `Form1.Designer.cs` file, you have `chart1` defined as `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart you need to change that to be MyChart in the section where it is new'd (need to search for Charting.Chart)

Comment: I've changed the code for the MyChart but beyond that I don't know what you mean in 1,2, and 3. What I think you mean is (1)`private Form1(){...PropertyGrid propertyGrid1 = new PropertyGrid();}` (2) No clue (3) `this.chart1 = new MyChart(); ... private MyChart chart1; `. For (4) I've done `private void propertyGrid_PropertyValueChange(...){ chart1.Invalidate()}; `

Comment: I updated to include all of the code except the `Form1.Designer.cs`

Comment: Also, you could just add the PropertyGrid using the designer, rather than instantiating and adding it in your constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and consideration. The advice your provided was invaluable and gave me the opportunity to continue with my project. Beyond that you've shown me a couple of things about C# I was unaware of. So again, thank you.